# ¿Se usa "brexit" o "brexiting" para despedirse pero no acabar de irse?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, extranjerismos, neologismos

He leído en ["Brexiting: el arte de despedirte de todo el mundo en una fiesta pero no marcharte nunca"](https://magnet.xataka.com/en-diez-minutos/brexiting-arte-despedirte-todo-mundo-fiesta-no-marcharte-nunca):

> ... que ... comienza a despedirse de todo el mundo. ... Pero al cabo de las horas sigue ahí. Se iba, pero no. ... Se había despedido, pero no planeaba marcharse.
>
> ... Hoy ya puedes utilizar un verbo para definir esa clase de actitud: "Brexiting".

En [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brexit) aparece:

> Brexit
> Verb: **Brexiting**
>
> The act of telling everyone at a gathering (party, meeting ... etc.), that you are leaving, but actually staying.
>
> Theresa is at the party, brexiting near the fridge for over an hour now.

¿Se usa habitualmente con ese sentido en español?

Comment: Yo uso "hacer un Brexit", y se lo explico a quien no lo entiende. Quizá sea pronto para saber cuánta influencia tendré.

Comment: Me pesa decir que la mayoría de la gente en EEUU no sabe ni papa de Brexit.  ( (Hispanoparlante o no.)  A veces quiero mencionarlo en un comentario a alguien, y con suerte han oído el término, pero aún así casi siempre me dicen que solo han oído el término.  No es de sorprender ya que sólo se menciona en los noticieros acá cuando sucede algo dramático.  Yo entendería con una breve explicación, pero yo sigo las noticias de la BBC.

Comment: Despite what Urban Dictionary may say I have never heard it being used as a verb in the three years since the referendum so it is vanishingly rare even in the country where you might expect it to be most used.

Comment: @mdewey precisely outside that country it becomes a part of the humour-vocabulary. In Russian, Polish (brexitować or breksitować) and probably other Slavic languages it *is* used, when you don't leave after you promise; in Spanish I've heard it as well.

Comment: @fedorqui: Hacía días que quería responder a tu comentario, pero se me acabó pasando... Me sonaba alguna cosa sobre que estaba aceptado en sitios sobre lenguas para corregir errores ortográficos, pero ahora creo que es sólo en [Italian.SE](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-may-i-correct-a-typo).

Comment: @Charo mmm podría debatirse en Meta. A mí me chirrió usar sugerencia de edición para corregir una tilde y luego añadir un espacio para llegar al mínimo. Me parece demasiado lío (dos revisores, un espacio puesto incorrectamente) para el beneficio que proporciona. Apostaría por comentarlo en la publicación para que alguien que ya tenga reputación suficiente edite sin tener que pasar por cola, o bien hacer más cambios relevantes a la publicación. Pero insisto es mi opinión, no algo discutido en esta comunidad específica

Answer (score 3):

No. El concepto es divertido y pertinente durante el período de un par de años en el que el Brexit ha sido un hecho en el horizonte pero que no acababa de concretarse.

Ahora que ya sí se va a producir de forma definitiva (31 de enero de 2020), pasará a ya no tener sentido y la broma necesitará de tanta explicación que si ya no es popular, dudo que acabe siéndolo.

Dado que no se ha popularizado en exceso durante el tiempo en que ha tenido sentido, yo creo que no dejará de ser una broma muy concreta que no va a tener ulterior trascendencia y que de aquí pocos años requerirá de mucha explicación para ser entendida.

Me vienen a la cabeza casos similares como [*hacer un Schettino*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidente_del_Costa_Concordia) que en su día tenían su gracia (humor negro) pero que cada vez cuesta más recordar porque los detalles del accidente se van olvidando al decaer el interés en el tema.

Comment: La pregunta es si se usa, no si se seguirá usando (y el futuro es difícil de predecir, no solo sobre el término, sino también con respecto al Brexit mismo). Y en tal caso la repuesta es afirmativa, a mi parecer.

Comment: Yo nunca lo he oído en España en conversación hablada. Solamente como tuit divertido, pero de poca viralidad